# Cassandra killed by O/S without error in logs

Tags: cassandra

One node of my cassandra cluster breaks very often like every day. It mostly breaks in the morning most probably because of memory consumption by other jobs. But I don't see any error msg in the logs. Following are the log messages when it breaks:

INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:313] 2016-04-07 07:19:19,629 Memtable.java:385 - Completed flushing /data/cassandra/data/system/compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca/system-compaction_history-ka-6666-Data.db (6945 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1459914506391, position=14934142)
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:313] 2016-04-07 07:19:19,631 Memtable.java:346 - Writing Memtable-sstable_activity@823770964(21691 serialized bytes, 7605 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:313] 2016-04-07 07:19:19,650 Memtable.java:385 - Completed flushing /data/cassandra/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/system-sstable_activity-ka-7558-Data.db (13689 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1459914506391, position=14934142)
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:1176] 2016-04-07 07:19:19,651 CompactionTask.java:140 - Compacting [SSTableReader(path='/data/cassandra/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/system-sstable_activity-ka-7557-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/data/cassandra/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/system-sstable_activity-ka-7556-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/data/cassandra/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/system-sstable_activity-ka-7555-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/data/cassandra/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/system-sstable_activity-ka-7558-Data.db')]
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:1176] 2016-04-07 07:19:19,696 CompactionTask.java:270 - Compacted 4 sstables to [/data/cassandra/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/system-sstable_activity-ka-7559,].  46,456 bytes to 9,197 (~19% of original) in 45ms = 0.194910MB/s.  1,498 total partitions merged to 216.  Partition merge counts were {1:675, 2:33, 3:11, 4:181, }
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:312] 2016-04-07 07:19:19,717 Memtable.java:385 - Completed flushing /data/cassandra/data/system/size_estimates-618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86/system-size_estimates-ka-8014-Data.db (849738 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1459914506391, position=14934142)

I know that the OS kills it but how to find the root cause of the problem and if any config changes can be done for cassandra?

Comment: I would go for a memory problem, then I guess because the os kills it, it doesn't have time to write in the log. Check the memory consumption

Comment: This is what I'm getting:

Comment: Out of memory: Kill process 81863 (java) score 51 or sacrifice child
Killed process 81863, UID 501, (java) total-vm:12786988kB, anon-rss:1577236kB, file-rss:11756kB

Comment: yeah it seems to be that. Do you have any operation that only runs on the morning? like compaction?

Comment: No not as such, but there are a lot of jobs that insert data on the mornings.

Comment: Is it possible to delay these operations? Do you need the data right away?

Comment: Yes, this is required in the morning only because the jobs take arount 2 hours to complete its execution.

Comment: what are the setups of your nodes? (hardware spec)

Comment: it should be more than enough, then I guess you should add more nodes to your cluster, or maybe the workload is not well balanced and some of your nodes do nothing...

Comment: you should try to see how the data is scatter accross you cluster (memory usage mostly) and try to find what does the job use to execute

Comment: If the O/S is killing it there should be a message in the O/S logs.

Comment: @Raedwald it is written in the comment I think: Out of memory: Kill process 81863 (java) score 51 or sacrifice child Killed process 81863, UID 501, (java) total-vm:12786988kB, anon-rss:1577236kB, file-rss:11756kB